# Deploying apex class and trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created an apex trigger that runs when an `Event` is deleted to notify an external API of the deletion. All the trigger does is invoke a static future method in an apex class to make the HTTP callout request. So I have one apex trigger, and one apex class that I need to deploy to production. Note I have not written any tests since all it does is make an external callout.

To deploy I am using [this process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_deploy.htm) of creating an outbound change set, selecting my apex trigger and class, deploying it from my sandbox, and deploying it in production.

In production when i click deploy it asks me which tests I want to run, which I left as default. Then the deploy fails and blames an external apex test unrelated to my apex code.

My question is,

- **Can I deploy without running all tests on every apex class?**
- **Is my apex code required to have tests deployed with it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deploy:

- Your trigger must be exercised by a testmethod
- Your @future class need not be exercised by a testmethod in order to deploy provided that you have at least 75% coverage across all Apex
- You can specify which tests to run when you deploy. You do not need to run all tests

*That said, it is "developer negligence" to not write testmethods for each trigger and class that cover the code paths and assert that the code does what it is supposed to do*

Comment: So even if the trigger has no side effect (in salesforce) it should still be run by a test? And can I deploy with out running tests from all existing apex classes?

Comment: Trigger must have test coverage to deploy

Comment: +1. Additionally, triggers that make an HTTP callout per record are highly vulnerable to governor limits issues and should be carefully bulkified or replaced with another technology, such as Change Data Capture.

Comment: is it possible to deploy the change set without running all apex tests? My org seems to have pre-existing tests failing beyond my app's scope.

Comment: @jefferson Yes... But be aware that you must meet 75% coverage for every class tested if you choose to run only selected tests.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense. Because when running all tests it mandated only 1% coverage. Thanks for explaining